# Facebook Like button shows the "Confirm" link, but still cannot Like after confirming

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

About 90% of the time, when I click on the Like button on my website, the confirm link shows up. When I click confirm, the popup appears and I click "Like". However, the confirm link is still there and my Like was not counted. I clicked confirm multiple times, but it still does not work. I refreshed the page many times, and about 10% of the time, the confirm link never shows up and I can Like it normally.

I heard about the Facebook Linter (aka debugger). I "linted" my page and I still cannot Like it.

Here's an example page: http://linksku.com/news/funny/i-like-steve-jobs-less-and-less-the-more-i-read-about-him/ (the bottom portion is loaded in an iframe).

Comment: Works for me every time. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Strange, it works in Firefox. I was using Chrome. I disabled all my extensions in Chrome, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am using Chrome as well, that's the browser I tested and I have absolutely no addons.

Comment: This is what I got on Safari: "Facebook's new Like button has been very glitchy recently. If you cannot Like this article, please click here."

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and got the same message as leo.vingi

Comment: That's a message that I added because the Like button isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't got the open graph namespace included in your html tag. That might cause weird behaviour. Try updating that to see if anything improves. An example of what it should look like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

see [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Answer (score -1):

Load Facebook SDK This Way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: '111111111111111', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because of link redirection. Suppose you are making the button to like the following link:

`http://example.com/abc.php?product=100`

but when someone opens the above link by typing into the web browser, they get redirected to the following link (just giving an example)

`http://example.com/abc/def`

So make sure you put the correct link which is to be liked in the like button. In other words, if you will put `http://example.com/abc/def` in the link button, it won't ask for Confirmation.