# Like button (Confirm)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have Facebook Like button but it is not showing in my timeline. When I clicked the like button in my website. It will change to Confirm that once I clicked this, small window will popped up to like that product. In the link of that small window it says something like this

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/confirm/like?iframe_referer=http%3A%2F%2F3beacheschemist.doublet.com.au%2Fproductdetail.aspx%3Fname%3DSWISSE-HAND-CREAM-WITH-VIT-F---POMEGRANATE-100ML&secure=false&plugin=like&return_params=%7B%22api_key%22%3A%22171681722971300%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22en_US%22%2C%22sdk%22%3A%22joey%22%2C%22channel_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Dffcb50044%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F3beacheschemist.doublet.com.au%252Ff39b47030%26domain%3D3beacheschemist.doublet.com.au%26relation%3Dparent.parent%22%2C%22href%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F3beacheschemist.doublet.com.au%2Fproductdetail.aspx%3Fname%3DSWISSE-HAND-CREAM-WITH-VIT-F---POMEGRANATE-100ML%22%2C%22node_type%22%3A%22link%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22450%22%2C%22layout%22%3A%22standard%22%2C%22colorscheme%22%3A%22light%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22recommend%22%2C%22show_faces%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22send%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22extended_social_context%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22ret%22%3A%22sentry%22%2C%22act%22%3A%22connect%22%7D

Before, it is working.All of a sudden I need to change anything which is I don't know.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083996/facebook-like-button-is-asking-to-confirm-the-action

Answer (score 0):

First, always use the like button generator:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Second, it helps in many cases to use the like button with an app id. Usually the spam confirmation does not show up that often if you use an app id for the facebook integration.

Example (fill in the appId):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

If that does not work, you can only wait, or maybe it helps to refresh the liked URL in the Facebook debugger:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug