# Facebook App Like server error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a sample app that has a 'Like' button. It works before but now it doesn't.
I've tested this on jsfiddle.net before and it works too. But after I've uploaded my files on a server it has a bug. The 'Like' button pops up and then has this error:

> https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/confirm/like?iframe_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fns2383.hostgator.com%2F~caryucla%2Fbpcontest%2FHTML%2FContestHome.php%2F&secure=true&plugin=like&return_params=%7B%22api_key%22%3A%22301719366592208%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22en_US%22%2C%22sdk%22%3A%22joey%22%2C%22ref%22%3A%22.UKWNYwbFB-8.like%22%2C%22channel_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D17%23cb%3Df13bb8c95%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fns2383.hostgator.com%252Ff2bf9f920%26domain%3Dns2383.hostgator.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent%22%2C%22href%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FDummy-Page-for-Testing%2F375795832160%22%2C%22node_type%22%3A%22link%22%2C%22width%22%3A%2290%22%2C%22font%22%3A%22arial%22%2C%22layout%22%3A%22button_count%22%2C%22colorscheme%22%3A%22light%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22like%22%2C%22show_faces%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22send%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22extended_social_context%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22ret%22%3A%22sentry%22%2C%22act%22%3A%22connect%22%7D

I've already read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356228/like-button-confirm) on SO already and followed the answer but still didn't work. Any views on this error?

PS:
I am all in all fairly new to this.

and here's the sample code I'm using:

```
    <?php  
include_once("../incs/dbcon.php");
require_once('AppInfo.php');
require_once('utils.php');
require_once('../sdk/src/facebook.php');

//This gets the signed_request from FB which checks the 'liked' status on the current page
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$app_data = isset($data["app_data"]) ? $data["app_data"] : '';
$_REQUEST["fb_page_id"] = $data["page"]["id"];
$access_admin = $data["page"]["admin"] == 1;
$has_liked = $data["page"]["liked"] == 1;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
));


$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
try {
// Fetch the viewer's basic information
$basic = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
// If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
// cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit();
}
}

// This fetches some things that you like . 'limit=*" only returns * values.
// To see the format of the data you are retrieving, use the "Graph API
// Explorer" which is at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=4'), 'data', array());

// This fetches 4 of your friends.
$friends = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=4'), 'data', array());

// And this returns 16 of your photos.
$photos = idx($facebook->api('/me/photos?limit=16'), 'data', array());

// Here is an example of a FQL call that fetches all of your friends that are
// using this app
$app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
));
}

// Fetch the basic info of the app that they are using
$app_info = $facebook->api('/'. AppInfo::appID());

$app_name = idx($app_info, 'name', '');
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title><?php echo he($app_name); ?></title>


<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# bpapptestbpapptest: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/bpapptestbpapptest#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="301719366592208" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="bpapptestbpapptest:video" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Video" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/Images/BPIcon.png" />      

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="301719366592208" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="object" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Object" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/Images/BPIcon.png" /> 
<link href="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function logResponse(response) {
if (console && console.log) {
console.log('The response was', response);
}
}

$(function(){
// Set up so we handle click on the buttons
$('#postToWall').click(function() {
FB.ui(
{
method : 'feed',
link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
},
function (response) {
// If response is null the user canceled the dialog
if (response != null) {
logResponse(response);
}
}
);
});

$('#sendToFriends').click(function() {
FB.ui(
{
method : 'send',
link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
},
function (response) {
// If response is null the user canceled the dialog
if (response != null) {
logResponse(response);
}
}
);
});

$('#sendRequest').click(function() {
FB.ui(
{
method  : 'apprequests',
message : $(this).attr('data-message')
},
function (response) {
// If response is null the user canceled the dialog
if (response != null) {
logResponse(response);
}
}
);
});
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '301719366592208', // App ID
channelUrl : '  https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/HTML/channel.html', // Channel File
status     : true, // check login status
cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
oauth        : true,
xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
});

// Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in using the Login button
//FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
// We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
// Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
// window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
// post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
// user asking if they want to send data again.
//window.location = window.location;});
//FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);});
};
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=301719366592208";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/CSS/jquery-ui.css" /><!--http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css-->
<script src="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><!--http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js-->

<script src="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script><!--http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js-->
<script src="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/javascript/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        $(function onclick() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Register?": function() {
                 window.location="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/HTML/RegForm.php"; 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    }
);      
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Content">

<div id="header">
<div id="LogoDiv">
<img id="logo" src="  https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/Images/Bp logo.png"></div><!--end of LogoDiv-->

<div id="LogoTextDiv">
<p id="LogoText">Fashion & Compassion Contest</p></div><!--end of LogoTextDiv-->
</div><!--end of header-->

<div id="DummyRow1"></div><!--end of DummyRow-->

<div id="BGForm">

<div id="Home">
<div id="Welcome">
<h1 id="WelcomeText">Welcome to Banana Peel's Fashion and Compassion Contest App!</h1>
</div><!--end of Welcome-->

<div id="HomeMechanics">
<h2>Contest Mechanics:</h2>

<div id="FBLogIn" class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="OnRequestPermission();"></div><!--end of FBLogIn div-->

<p id="Mec">To join the contest, Participants must first Log In through Facebook and LIKE Banana Peel's Facebook Fan Page. After liking the page you will be able to click the registration link button.</p>



<div id="LikeBox"> 
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" addthis:url="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dummy-Page-for-Testing/375795832160" addthis:title="Banana Peel Page" onclick="onclick()"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div> 
<div id="dialog-confirm">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Thank you for liking our page!</p>
</div><!--end of dialog-confirm div--><!--end of class addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/javascript/addthis_widget.js"></script>
</div><!--end of LikeBoxhttp://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-50a0584951afe01c--> 
</div><!--end of HomeMechanics-->

<div id="ContestantsBG">
<img src="https://ns2383.hostgator.com/~caryucla/bpcontest/Images/BPpic.jpg"/>
</div><!--end of ContestantBG-->

<div id="GalleryButton">
<a id="BackLink" href="../HTML/ContestantGallery.php"><input type="button" value="VIEW GALLERY OF CONTESTANTS"></a>
</div><!--end of GalleryButton-->

</div><!--end of Home-->
</div><!--end of BGForm-->

</div><!--end of Content-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what is the url from the like button/box?

Comment: @NoScope:
here's the url of the like button: 
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dummy-Page-for-Testing/375795832160

Comment: Like I thought... a like link gets scraped by Facebook and has to pass the Facebook parser. Otherwise Facebook will mark your link as "spam" after a while and then the confirm box shows up (which often doesn't work as well). Your link has to pass the debugger in order to keep working (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). For example try to parse http://www.facebook.com in the dubber, you need to get that result of a like link as well. But you want to like a Facebook page so you can't edit the page yourself. I don't really see a real solution here I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This message is what Facebook use to stop Like-jacking and prevent spam. It can also appear if the Like button has been added to a website / domain for the first time. Give it time and the message will disappear once Facebook is satisfied that your site isn't doing any of the above things.