# Facebook events does not fire when login on Like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want to have FB like button:

1) if user is NOT logged in - like button triggers login(), I get informed and show/hide some content.
2) if user IS logged in - this case I've already handled.

The problem occurs only when user try to login **after clicked Like button**. It works only after I logged in and refresh page. Simple Like button:

```
<div
    class="fb-like"
    data-href="URL_TO_PAGE"
    data-width="200"
    data-layout="button"
    data-action="like"
    data-size="large"
    data-show-faces="false"
    data-share="false">
</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
var cb = function(response) {
    console.log( "Triggered" );
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init( {
        appId: 'APP_ID',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
    } );
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', cb); // not working
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', cb); // not working
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', cb); // not working
}
(function ( d, s, id ) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName( s )[ 0 ];
    if ( d.getElementById( id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement( s );
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore( js, fjs );
}( document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk' ));
```

I read in the Facebook Javascript Documentation that above events are triggering after `FB.login()` invokes. Apparently in this case does not fire that event.

**Note:** when I setting `FB.login` on some div it works fine:

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="FB.login();">
```

but I need only Like button implicitly

Comment: Why would you need to display something different depending on whether the user is already logged in to Facebook or not?

Answer (score 1):

The same Problem here.
I need to fire a Function after the "Like it" Button has been clicked.
When a User is already logged in, a Popup is shown where the User has to Confirm the "Like". After confirming the Like the Popup closes, but the Callback is not fired.
When not logged in, the Login Popup appears before.

I'm developing from localhost, but added my localhost Domain to the App.
This is the URL from the Confirm Popup

EDIT: This explains the Confirmation Popup
[Facebook App Like server error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408887/facebook-app-like-server-error)

But what about triggering a Function right after Login?
Is this possible?

```html
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/confirm/like?iframe_referer=http://www.test.localhost/&kid_directed_site=false&secure=true&plugin=like&return_params={"action":"like","app_id":"MY-APP-ID","channel":"http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/lY4eZXm_YWu.js?version=42#cb=f1748a217514654&domain=www.test.localhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.localhost%2Ff19fff7af9e9ab&relation=parent.parent","container_width":"1418","href":"https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookepage","layout":"button_count","locale":"de_DE","sdk":"joey","share":"false","show_faces":"false","size":"large","ret":"sentry","act":"like"}
```

```html
<html lang="de" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'MY-APP-ID',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            status: true,
            version: 'v2.11'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() {
            console.log('edge.create');
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function() {
            console.log('edge.remove');
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

fbAsyncInit as neme suggest is asynchronous function so you will need to call your function on login success. I think "FB.getLoginStatus()" can be used to detect when login is finsihed so you can try something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'APP_ID',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.status === 'connected') { 
           FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', cb); 
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', cb); 
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', cb); 
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: nope, that doesn't work. I've tried without ``if`` for simplicity. I don't know why but I have feeling that ``subscribe`` doesn't work if you are not logged in

Comment: Yeah that is probably true, sorry I don't have more know-how in FB APIs but maybe this link can help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: Actually looking at it now, maybe the problem is just with initializing the callback function. I have made the change in the code, maybe this will work?