# Like button turns to "confirm" on brand new app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, confirm

I've recently created an app for a client where they want separate like buttons next to each of their products. The like buttons are the iframe variants and use a unique URL to the app to separate the products.

The like buttons require the "confirm" action and has done so since the beginning, something which the client (unsurprisingly) isn't very happy with. Is there anything that I've done to cause the like buttons to react this way (iframe inside iframe, testing by liking/unliking URLs quickly, CSS styling that seems mischievous, etc.) and what can I do to fix it?

I've tried running the URLs through the URL debugger ([example](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://smash-products.like.st/products/products/products/view/512c8a2d-1010-4efd-be52-3ecdb0095222)) but it doesn't solve the problem or show any errors/warnings.

The app in question: https://www.facebook.com/Smash.sjokolade/app_567454876598963

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like button is asking to confirm the action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083996/facebook-like-button-is-asking-to-confirm-the-action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Confirm" on the Like Button is a security feature Facebook has put in place to prevent Like-jacking / click-jacking and getting users to Like spam / malware sites. You may see it occasionally on new domains / apps.

However, there is no way to turn this off. It will go away after a number of legitimate likes have been made on the domain / app. Until then, you'll just have to wait it out.